# Native ZFS doesn't free up space when deleting files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, disk-space-utilization

I'm running native ZFS on Ubuntu 11.10 with 2x2 TB drives in a mirrored setup. The ZFS file system is mounted directly in Ubuntu and not through NFS or something like that, the permissions are set too 777.

My problem is that when I delete a file it would disappear as you'd expect but when I type zfs list it's still reporting used space as if the file was still there. I've wait a couple of hours and I'm currently running a scrub to see if that fixes it but that shouldn't be necessary, should it?

Comment: Got any snaps in place?

Comment: Yeah, http://serverfault.com/questions/160912/zfs-file-deletion-and-its-relationship-to-disk-space seems to cover it.

Comment: No, I don't have any snapshots or compression on that particular dataset but I've found the solution so I'll answer my own question. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty ridiculous I guess; it turned out that Ubuntu moved the files to .Trash1000 but wouldn't allow the Recycle Bin to empty the .trash-folders on my ZFS datasets. I'm guessing this is a permissions issue or something since my ZFS datasets are mounted with root and then I ran chmod 777 on all of them to allow for my user to use them.

Anyways, deleting the .Trash1000 folder fixed the "problem".

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!